# Multiple variable with x for x

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

Hello I have this code with Python :

```
for i in range(0,2):
    for j in range(0,2):
        print i+j
```

And I would like to have something like this :

```
a = [x for x in ...]
```

which displays exactly the same results that the loop for ie :

```
0
1
1
2
```

But I don't know how to replace a loop for by a comprehension list because in this case I have two variable and not one.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you.

Comment: Where did you get the term "comprehension list"? There is no such thing as a "comprehension list" in Python - there are list comprehensions, which are a way of building lists - but I'm wondering if there's a common source people are getting the incorrect terminology from.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this sample code:

```
a = [i+j for i in range(0,2) for j in range(0,2)]
print(a)
```

Comment: You do not need this line `a=[]`